# How does a program manage type information?

Tags: c++, types

I was just wondering, how is the type information managed internaly by a c++ program?

eg. float f; needs 32bits of memory. But since all bits are used to save the value, how does the program remember it to be of the type float?

(I know this is quite a noob question...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to differentiate between static (compile-time) type and dynamic (run-time) type.

***Static*** types are managed by the compiler ***during compilation*** and, except for the type-specific semantics embedded in the resulting code, forgotten at run-time.

***Dynamic*** type information is usually held in so-called type-specific "virtual tables", which hold pointers to all virtual functions the type has and what little run-time type information C++ supports. Only polymorphic types (those with at least one virtual function) will have dynamic type information attached.

Answer (score 7):

Normally (that is, unless you use RTTI) the program does not know that kind of thing (although the compiler is very strict about checking it to avoid errors). The program code just executes "as if", i.e. if you wrote some code that uses a float variable, then it will execute floating point instructions on whatever value it loads from the respective memory address.

If you do use RTTI (runtime type information) then the compiler stores a *lot* of extra information in the executable, which also lets you determine a type at runtime.

Lastly, with virtual inheritance, some kind of type information (although not directly accessible) is stored in the vtable. For every object type (not every single object, but for the type, i.e. all objects together) the compiler generates a special "jump table" which lets it map the overloaded functions correctly. You don't know about this and you don't see anything from it, but it will "just work". Nevertheless, it is a kind of type information, implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

C++ generally doesn't need any type information since it is a static language - meaning that all type-checking is done in compile-time rather than run-time.

Say you have this code:

```
float fn(float a) { return a + 1.f; }
```

...the compiler already knows that `fn` should receive a float, add 1.f to it, and return a float. It can generate the machine code accordingly and doesn't need to look anything up in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler manages types. The running executable doesn't. For the executable, those 4 bytes in memory are just that, 4 bytes in memory. But the compiler has ensured that either only integer instructions or only float instructions operate on them.

Comment: That's not true. There's dynamic type information you can use it, too, when calling virtual functions, invoking `typeid` or `dynamic_Cast`.

Comment: This is not entirely true, what about RTTI?

Comment: The question was related to simple types and the confusion was on how this simple type information could be "stored" given well known fixed size data. RTTI and the related mechanisms is a completely different topic IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably helpful to note that c++ once compiled is assembly language for whatever cpu instruction set the compiler is targeting.

A simple thing like "float i = 2.0 + n;" gets turned into "set aside 32 bits, take 2.0 and this other group of 32 bits, and perform a 32bit FLOATING POINT version of ADD.  Then ASSIGN that to the 32 bits we just reserved"